# Python code for finding top 5 processes using cpu

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I am new to python and I have a simple problem of finding the top processes using the CPU. I was able to do it in shell using ps and sort.

I have checked few but links but it do not help partly because the function is defined as below,

```
define find_proc(ps_input)
```

ps_input will be something like below,

```
PID        CPU          PROG
12658       20             ABC
19265       80             BCD
21265       60             BAD
19655       11             BCE
```

Can someone help me in this program..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) is the one I would recommend. From the PyPI site, here is the package description,

> psutil (process and system utilities) is a cross-platform library for
>   retrieving information on running **processes and system utilization
>   (CPU, memory, disks, network, sensors) in Python**. It is useful
>   mainly for system monitoring, profiling and limiting process resources
>   and management of running processes. It implements many
>   functionalities offered by UNIX command line tools such as: ps, top,
>   lsof, netstat, ifconfig, who, df, kill, free, nice, ionice, iostat,
>   iotop, uptime, pidof, tty, taskset, pmap.

To address your problem statement, here is the sample I took from the site which list outs process sorted by memory - https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/

```
def getListOfProcessSortedByMemory():
    '''
    Get list of running process sorted by Memory Usage
    '''
    listOfProcObjects = []
    # Iterate over the list
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       try:
           # Fetch process details as dict
           pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username'])
           pinfo['vms'] = proc.memory_info().vms / (1024 * 1024)
           # Append dict to list
           listOfProcObjects.append(pinfo);
       except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
           pass

    # Sort list of dict by key vms i.e. memory usage
    listOfProcObjects = sorted(listOfProcObjects, key=lambda procObj: procObj['vms'], reverse=True)

    return listOfProcObjects
```

Complete code is available in the above site; you may need to tweak accordingly to list based on cpu usage. Hope this helps.

Comment: please, fix the indentation in your answer's code. Indentation is not an 'optional whatever' in Python.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Here is some example usages of psutil:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil
# gives a single float value
psutil.cpu_percent()
# gives an object with many fields
psutil.virtual_memory()
# you can convert that object to a dictionary 
dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil
processes = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid']):
    p = psutil.Process(pid=proc.pid)
    processes.append(p.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent']))
print("--------------------Top 5 by CPU---------------------------------")
cpu = sorted(processes, key=lambda i: i['cpu_percent'], reverse=True)
count = 0
while (count < 5):   
    count = count + 1
    print(cpu[count])
```